# Opencv, error while reading XML file for camera calibration

Tags: xml, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm using [the code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/calib3d/camera_calibration) provided by opencv for camera calibration.
I've edited the settings file to contain my own directories, and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<images>
"20170720_024951.jpg"
"20170720_025001.jpg"
"20170720_025014.jpg"
"20170720_025023.jpg"
"20170720_025034.jpg"
"20170720_025048.jpg"
"20170720_025103.jpg"
"20170720_025115.jpg"
"20170720_025124.jpg"
"20170720_025133.jpg"
"20170720_025147.jpg"
"20170720_025155.jpg"
"20170720_025211.jpg"
</images>
```

I am providing the full image path, but getting this error:

> Invalid input detected. Application stopping.

here is the part of the code at which I'm getting the error:

```
Settings s;
const string inputSettingsFile = "C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/calibration/x.xml";
FileStorage fs(inputSettingsFile, FileStorage::READ); // Read the settings
if (!fs.isOpened())
{
    cout << "Could not open the configuration file: \"" << inputSettingsFile << "\"" << endl;
    return -1;
}
fs["Settings"] >> s;
fs.release();                                         // close Settings file
//! [file_read]

//FileStorage fout("settings.yml", FileStorage::WRITE); // write config as YAML
//fout << "Settings" << s;

if (!s.goodInput)
{
    cout << "Invalid input detected. Application stopping. " << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

the origin file provided by oencv didn't contain "" around the attributes(paths of the images) so I have tried first to insert the path of the images **in the XML file** without **using double quotations** "path/image.jpg" -> path/image, but the following exception was raised:

> OpenCV Error: Parsing error (C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio
>   2013/Projects/calebration/x.xml(1): Attribute value should
>   be put into single or double quotes) in icvXMLParseTag, file
>   C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp,
>   line 2157

and after adding "" as suggested by someone, the exception disappear but still stuck at the first error (which is telling *as I suppose* that the format of the xml file is not correct)

Comment: Have you tried using backslash \ instead of slash / ?? not sure if this is the case in xml but you may need to escape the backslash

Comment: thank you so much, I have tried both \ and / but there were other issues, solved in my answer below !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was solved:
for the second problem

> OpenCV Error: Parsing error (C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio
>   2013/Projects/calebration/x.xml(1): Attribute value should be put into
>   single or double quotes) in icvXMLParseTag, file
>   C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp,
>   line 2157

it turns out that the paths to my images contains spaces, so simply was was solved by moving the images to another directory containing no spaces.

for the first problem I was totally a fool!
to use the code you need two xml files!
the first one is where you put the settings of the calibration (e.g. whether you are using a chess board, circles grid, or whatever, and the size of the board you are using , as well the directory to the second xml where your images exists, ....)
in the second xml file you insert the images as shown in my question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing `</opencv_storage>` at the end of your file. You need to close the tag for the XML to be valid.

Comment: thanks so much!
I was missing the </opencv_storage> but there was also other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, just remove the spaces in the directory path and it should work

C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/calebration/x.xml

should be:
C:/Users/user/Documents/Visual_Studio_2013/Projects/calebration/x.xml